# Matching objects from different types by a common property in Java

Tags: java, collections, java-8, match, java-stream

I have the following classes:

```
abstract class Executor {
String executorType;

public Executor(String executorType) {this.executorType = executorType;}

public void execute(String dataContent);
}

class Data {
String dataType;
String dataContent;
}
```

Given a list of Datas, and a list of Executors(concrete ones that extend Executor), I want that each executor will call execute only on the data with the same type as their types. In other words executor will execute on data only if executor.executorType == data.dataType

How can I do it shortly and with good performance, using streams, collectors and other things that are supplied by Java 8?

Here's an example that I've made, but I think I can do better:

(Notes:
1. In my example, I create a map between executors and data on which they can run their execute() method. However, if there's a solution that skips the map creation and instantly run execute(), that would be better
2. In my example I assumed that Executor is a concrete class, not abstract, just for the convenience.

```
List<Executor> executorList = Arrays.asList(new Executor("one"), new Executor("two"), new Executor("three"));
List<Data> dataList = Arrays.asList(new Data("one","somecontent"), new Data("two","someOtherContent"), new Data("one","longContent"));
Map<List<Executor>, List<Data>> stringToCount = dataList.stream().collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(t-> executorList.stream().filter(n -> n.executorType.equals(t.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do it shortly and with good performance, using streams, collectors and other things that are supplied by Java 8?

So what is exactly your goal? Good performance or using Java 8 Streams?

With streams it would be something like:

```
dataList
    .forEach(data -> executorList
        .stream()
        .filter(executor -> Objects.equals(data.dataType, executor.executorType))
        .findAny()
        .map(executor -> executor.execute(data.dataContent)));
```

Not sure about the syntax, but something along the lines.

But I'd actually make a `Map<String, Executor>` on `Executor.executorType` first and then just `executors.get(data.dataType)`. You could also implement a `VoidExecutor` which does nothing and call

```
executors.getOrDefault(data.dataType, VoidExecutor.INSTANCE).execute(data.dataContent);
```

With a hash map you may expect contant-time lookups.

Comment: My goal was to make it run with the best time complexity and be elegantly written, but I assumed it couldn't be done better without using streams. I was wrong of course. Regarding the map, this is something I thought of using but I still preferred to avoid it.